# Revisar si hay tweets repetidos en MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter-api

Tengo un método que, gracias a Twython, guarda los tweets en MongoDB tal cual está en mi pregunta [Maintaining a mongodb with tweets that match a given tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136798/maintaining-a-mongodb-with-tweets-that-match-a-given-tag)

```
def getSearchTagTwitter(hashtag):
    db = connexMongoDB()
    t = loginTwython()
    search = t.search(q=hashtag, count=100)
    data = search['statuses']
    try:
        db.twittersearch.create_index('id_str')
        for tweet in data:
            try :
                db.twittersearch.insert_one(tweet)
            except :
                db.twittersearch.update_one({"id_str": tweet['id_str']}, tweet) 
    except Exception:
        print "Error al buscar hashtag"
        time.sleep(60*15) #15 minutos
        getSearchTagTwitter(hashtag)
```

Creo que no funciona correctamente y quiero comprobar si el valor de `id_str` no esta repetido a través del MongoDB shell y/o desde Python. He probado con lo siguiente pero no me da ningún resultado:

```
db.twittersearch.find({'id_str':{$in:["numerodeid_str"]}})
```

Edito: Simplifico la pregunta ¿Desde Python, cómo podría comprobar si no tengo repetidos en un mongodb ya creado? Actualmente me conecto con pymongo, y puedo ver que he creado la colección.

Comment: No importa si es desde la consola del MongoDB o desde Python, el tema es que estás insertando documentos en las colecciones y no los puedes encontrar, hay que encontrar primero ese problema. ¿Qué estás usando actualmente para conectarte desde Python?

Comment: Me conecto con pymongo. Lo voy a indicar en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún resultado si haces `db.twittersearch.count()`?

Comment: Sí, me aparece un número, e incluso veo que se incrementa cada x tiempo al volver al consultarlo. Al introducir db.twittersearch.findOne() me muestra un tweet completo. Si busco sólo db.twittersearch.find() me salen varias veces seguidas el mismo tweet, por eso creo que hay repetidos. O estoy guardando el mismo tweet una y otra vez. No se.

Comment: Al parecer el problema está en tu código entonces, voy a tratar de replicar tu caso, que hashtag estas usando?

Comment: Mira mi edición

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para grabar en tu colección del MongoDB estás usando `id_str`:

```
db.twittersearch.create_index('id_str')
# ... 
db.twittersearch.update_one({"id_str": tweet['id_str']}, tweet)
```

Y al hacer el query estás usando el campo incorrecto `str_id` (al revés de `id_str`):

```
db.twittersearch.find({'str_id':{$in:["numerodestr_id"]}})
```

Lo correcto sería:

```
db.twittersearch.find({'id_str':{$in:["numerodestr_id"]}})
```

A menos, claro, que solo sea un error de tipeo o de copiado/pegado

---

### Actualización después de la edición

He creado un script sencillo para replicar tu caso usando el hashtag `python` y obteniendo solo 10 tweets:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pymongo import MongoClient
from twython import Twython


client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

def get_tweets(hashtag='wtf'):
    twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    search = twitter.search(q=hashtag, count=10)
    data = search['statuses']
    for tweet in data:
        try:
            db.twittersearch.insert_one(tweet)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error al insertar: %s" % e
            db.twittersearch.update_one({'id_str': tweet['id_str']}, tweet)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_tweets(hashtag='python')
```

Y no me da problemas, si hago algunos queries de prueba en la consola del MongoDB:

```
> db.twittersearch.find({}, {"id_str": 1, "_id": 0})
{ "id_str" : "700315462568120320" }
{ "id_str" : "700315461850804224" }
{ "id_str" : "700315438169747457" }
{ "id_str" : "700315421900148736" }
{ "id_str" : "700315421887619076" }
{ "id_str" : "700315350299049988" }
{ "id_str" : "700315332838301698" }
{ "id_str" : "700315321689833473" }
{ "id_str" : "700315301594796032" }
{ "id_str" : "700315293177008128" }

> db.twittersearch.find({"id_str": {$in: ["700315461850804224"]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c5caae2fbb7114134d0bac"), "contributors" : null, "truncated" : false, "text" : "RT @dmeishappy_: กระเป๋าของฟานี่คือ DIORAMA MINI BAG \nMETALLIC BLUE PYTHON ราคาราวๆ 98,000~ บาท #WelcomeTIFFANYtoThailand https://t.co/UnDp…", "is_quote_status" : false, "in_reply_to_status_id" : null, "id" : NumberLong("700315461850804224"), "favorite_count" : 0, "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", "retweeted" : false, "coordinates" : null, "entities" : { "symbols" : [ ], "user_mentions" : [ { "id" : 299006216, "indices" : [ 3, 15 ], "id_str" : "299006216", "screen_name" : "dmeishappy_", "name" : "น้องสดใส" } ], "hashtags" : [ { "indices" : [ 96, 121 ], "text" : "WelcomeTIFFANYtoThailand" } ], "urls" : [ ], "media" : [ { "source_user_id" : 299006216, "source_status_id_str" : "700301141263806464", "expanded_url" : "http://twitter.com/dmeishappy_/status/700301141263806464/photo/1", "display_url" : "pic.twitter.com/UnDpsznRJ6", "url" : "https://t.co/UnDpsznRJ6", "media_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cbf4Ka0UkAEWmhH.jpg", "source_user_id_str" : "299006216", "source_status_id" : NumberLong("700301141263806464"), "id_str" : "700301124960555009", "sizes" : { "large" : { "h" : 1024, "resize" : "fit", "w" : 669 }, "small" : { "h" : 520, "resize" : "fit", "w" : 340 }, "medium" : { "h" : 918, "resize" : "fit", "w" : 600 }, "thumb" : { "h" : 150, "resize" : "crop", "w" : 150 } }, "indices" : [ 122, 140 ], "type" : "photo", "id" : NumberLong("700301124960555009"), "media_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cbf4Ka0UkAEWmhH.jpg" } ] }, "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null, "in_reply_to_user_id" : null, "retweet_count" : 152, "id_str" : "700315461850804224", "favorited" : false, "retweeted_status" : { "contributors" : null, "truncated" : false, "text" : "กระเป๋าของฟานี่คือ DIORAMA MINI BAG \nMETALLIC BLUE PYTHON ราคาราวๆ 98,000~ บาท #WelcomeTIFFANYtoThailand https://t.co/UnDpsznRJ6", "is_quote_status" : false, "in_reply_to_status_id" : null, "id" : NumberLong("700301141263806464"), "favorite_count" : 13, "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "retweeted" : false, "coordinates" : null, "entities" : { "symbols" : [ ], "user_mentions" : [ ], "hashtags" : [ { "indices" : [ 79, 104 ], "text" : "WelcomeTIFFANYtoThailand" } ], "urls" : [ ], "media" : [ { "expanded_url" : "http://twitter.com/dmeishappy_/status/700301141263806464/photo/1", "display_url" : "pic.twitter.com/UnDpsznRJ6", "url" : "https://t.co/UnDpsznRJ6", "media_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cbf4Ka0UkAEWmhH.jpg", "id_str" : "700301124960555009", "sizes" : { "large" : { "h" : 1024, "resize" : "fit", "w" : 669 }, "small" : { "h" : 520, "resize" : "fit", "w" : 340 }, "medium" : { "h" : 918, "resize" : "fit", "w" : 600 }, "thumb" : { "h" : 150, "resize" : "crop", "w" : 150 } }, "indices" : [ 105, 128 ], "type" : "photo", "id" : NumberLong("700301124960555009"), "media_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cbf4Ka0UkAEWmhH.jpg" } ] }, "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null, "in_reply_to_user_id" : null, "retweet_count" : 152, "id_str" : "700301141263806464", "favorited" : false, "user" : { "follow_request_sent" : null, "has_extended_profile" : true, "profile_use_background_image" : true, "default_profile_image" : false, "id" : 299006216, "profile_background_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/449190232508747776/eVbVkbBq.png", "verified" : false, "profile_text_color" : "3E3417", "profile_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/699491224382676992/1RCFrGlC_normal.jpg", "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "6E096E", "entities" : { "description" : { "urls" : [ ] } }, "followers_count" : 12731, "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "000000", "id_str" : "299006216", "profile_background_color" : "ECEEE0", "listed_count" : 15, "is_translation_enabled" : false, "utc_offset" : -28800, "statuses_count" : 123360, "description" : "ก็แค่ทวิตเตอร์จำเป็นต้องจริงจังปร้าาาาา", "friends_count" : 260, "location" : "คิดให้ดีๆก่อนฟอลโล่ว", "profile_link_color" : "E81C4F", "profile_image_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/699491224382676992/1RCFrGlC_normal.jpg", "following" : null, "geo_enabled" : true, "profile_banner_url" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/299006216/1455606704", "profile_background_image_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/449190232508747776/eVbVkbBq.png", "screen_name" : "dmeishappy_", "lang" : "en", "profile_background_tile" : false, "favourites_count" : 4013, "name" : "น้องสดใส", "notifications" : null, "url" : null, "created_at" : "Sun May 15 10:19:10 +0000 2011", "contributors_enabled" : false, "time_zone" : "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "protected" : false, "default_profile" : false, "is_translator" : false }, "geo" : null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null, "possibly_sensitive" : false, "lang" : "und", "created_at" : "Thu Feb 18 12:49:37 +0000 2016", "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null, "place" : null, "metadata" : { "iso_language_code" : "und", "result_type" : "recent" } }, "user" : { "follow_request_sent" : null, "has_extended_profile" : true, "profile_use_background_image" : true, "default_profile_image" : false, "id" : 594309538, "profile_background_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/568400749038534656/SJRD7Zj6.jpeg", "verified" : false, "profile_text_color" : "3E4415", "profile_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/694513699344687106/DCKLb8Mz_normal.jpg", "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "99CC33", "entities" : { "url" : { "urls" : [ { "url" : "https://t.co/TKchFkPats", "indices" : [ 0, 23 ], "expanded_url" : "http://instagram.com/beastly_snowy", "display_url" : "instagram.com/beastly_snowy" } ] }, "description" : { "urls" : [ ] } }, "followers_count" : 319, "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "FFFFFF", "id_str" : "594309538", "profile_background_color" : "352726", "listed_count" : 10, "is_translation_enabled" : false, "utc_offset" : 25200, "statuses_count" : 79299, "description" : "#SONE @GirlsGeneration || Hwang Miyoung Stepanie Tiffany || // Taeny // Taeyeon Jessica Sunny Hyoyeon Yuri Sooyoung  YoonA SeoHyun // #notep #เอมน้ำ #OT9", "friends_count" : 255, "location" : "#Kamphaeng Phet Thailand", "profile_link_color" : "D02B54", "profile_image_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/694513699344687106/DCKLb8Mz_normal.jpg", "following" : null, "geo_enabled" : true, "profile_banner_url" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/594309538/1452856105", "profile_background_image_url" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/568400749038534656/SJRD7Zj6.jpeg", "screen_name" : "yeppoNOOO", "lang" : "en", "profile_background_tile" : true, "favourites_count" : 3413, "name" : "ONIAP° #ขุ่นแม่มา♥", "notifications" : null, "url" : "https://t.co/TKchFkPats", "created_at" : "Wed May 30 04:51:51 +0000 2012", "contributors_enabled" : false, "time_zone" : "Bangkok", "protected" : false, "default_profile" : false, "is_translator" : false }, "geo" : null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null, "possibly_sensitive" : false, "lang" : "und", "created_at" : "Thu Feb 18 13:46:31 +0000 2016", "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null, "place" : null, "metadata" : { "iso_language_code" : "und", "result_type" : "recent" } }
```

Creo que el problema está por otro lado, tal vez haya algo mas en tú código que se nos esté pasando.

Comment: Perdón, ha sido un error al escribirlo.

Comment: He adaptado tu código y ya no he tenido ningún problema. He investigado un poco más, y es probable que sólo se hubiera mencionado el hashtag 1 vez en los últimos 7 días. Y dado que no tenía ningún cambio, no se cambiaba en el mongodb. Aunque sigue sin cuadrarme que en cada iteración se guardará un nuevo registro... De todas maneras, muchisimas gracias por todo^^

Answer (score 1):

Añado otra solución que he encontrado, que es utilizar el update con el valor upsert a True. Así se sobrescribirá si hay algún duplicado y se creará un nuevo registro si no existe.

```
db.twittersearch.update({'id_str': tweet['id_str']}, tweet, upsert=True)
```